# Flex and Parsley Logging

Tags: apache-flex, logging, flash-builder, parsley

i'm looking for a possibility to log messages in my flex 4.5 Project. This should cover errormessages in remoteClasses, errorHandler or messages typing by hand.
After reading a lot of webpages, the solution from parslay looks good. i want to switch to this framework anyway.

the benefit is the possibility to configure the logging behavior at runtime. but i don't understand the documentation. perhaps because I'm brandnew in parsley. Also google has no fitting result.

Do you have already did this and it is possible for you to give me a few code snippets.
Thanks a lot

Frank

EDIT:
Because of  J_A_X justified criticism, i add my code, because i have partially succeeded.

First we need a config file, because i want to configure the logging behavior in runtime. This is a simple xml-file in the project root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects 
    xmlns="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley"
    xmlns:log="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/flex/logging"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley 
        http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/schema/2.3/parsley-core.xsd 
        http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/flex/logging 
        http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/schema/2.3/parsley-logging-flex.xsd"
    >

    <log:target level="info" type="components.SocketTarget">

    </log:target>

</objects>
```

This is my Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               initialize="onAppInitiallize(event)" 
               xmlns:parsley="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Label;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.logging.Log;

            import org.spicefactory.lib.logging.LogContext;
            import org.spicefactory.parsley.flex.logging.FlexLoggingXmlSupport;

            protected function onAppInitiallize(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                FlexLoggingXmlSupport.initialize();
                LogContext.getLogger(this);
                //Log.getLogger("myCat").info("MyInfo");
            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler():void
            {
                Log.getLogger(this.toString()).info("myMessage");
                Log.getLogger(this.toString()).fatal("myMessage");


            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <parsley:ContextBuilder>
            <parsley:XmlConfig file="config.xml"/>
        </parsley:ContextBuilder>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler()" label="SendLogToParsley" />
</s:Application>
```

At this point, the logging will work in the console of the flex builder, because parsley uses by default the TraceTarget. Now, i want to send my Logfiles to a socket. I wrote a litte rough SocketTarget.

```
package de.axurit.components
{
    import flash.net.Socket;

    import mx.logging.AbstractTarget;
    import mx.logging.LogEvent;
    import mx.logging.targets.LineFormattedTarget;

    public class SocketTarget extends AbstractTarget
    {
        private var _host:String;
        private var _port:int;
        private var _socket:Socket;

        public function SocketTarget(host:String = "localhost",port:int=8085)
        {
            _host = host;
            _port = port;
            _socket = new Socket (host,port);
            super();
        }

        override public function logEvent (event:LogEvent):void
        {
            trace ("logevent" + event.message);
            _socket.writeUTF(event.message + String.fromCharCode(13));
            _socket.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

In the parsley documentation i can see the comment

> The default target type created by this tag is a TraceTarget. You can
>   explicitly declare other target types:

If i add the type-attribute, i receive a Errormessage "One or more errors in BootstrapProcessor". The same as i received after a typo.

Can you give me some hints, how i can send my logs to a socket destination?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close if this question can't be cleaned up.  What exactly are you asking?  Just for examples?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Have you looked at the logging section in the Dev manual of Parsley?  What have you tried?  Where's the code?

Comment: yes you're right. yesterday i was a litte bit desperate. I was not sure, if it is possible in general and do not know, how and if i can implement this. All tries had ended in NIL. So my question was, if anyone have a simple example, how i can log something i parsley. I do not think that this is rarely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the socket, but never actually connect it.  Plus, if you're going to make a log target, make your class extend trace target and override the log function.

Comment: the socket is just a test. The methods to controll the connection will be written later. For this step, i need just the functionality. Now my class extends from TraceTarget. But the error bootstrap from parsley is still there when i add the type to the config.xml.
I did't found the method "log", do you mean logEvent?

Comment: uhh, i turn on the logging of parsley. one of the errormessages is "unknown class". My class "SocketTarget" hs the package name com.mydomain.components and has the name SocketTarget. What ist the coorect line in the parsley config? <log:target level="info" type="com.mydomain.components.SocketTarget">

Comment: You can't 'test' without connecting. Plus, from the code you put there, you're not extending TraceTarget, but AbstractTarget.  And thirdly, you only need to specify the target in the config like this: `<local:YourTraceTarget level="{LogEventLevel.ALL}" />`.  I've posted [something similar in my blog](http://www.michelboudreau.com/2010/07/13/firebugloggertarget-class/).

Comment: i have a connect. i wrote a little tool that opens a socket. yes you're right, my code points to AbstractTarget, but aftre your comment i change my app but not my question. In the parsley documentation, they wrote i have to config my parsley logger like my line above.

Comment: I wrote my own Logger. J_A_X answer is the only one, also the right one. Thank you even its not the solution in aspect with parsley. Frank